# Jenkins build failed but manually running is fine in plotly graph script

Tags: python, jenkins, plotly

I developed daily mail script in python. If I run into machine manually then it is working fine but If I had run via Jenkins It got failed. I am using plotly graph in script and error is also from plotly library.Here is my stack trace of failed jenkins.

```
+ /home/ubuntu/rest_api/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/rest_api/scripts/daily_analysis_report.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/rest_api/scripts/daily_analysis_report.py", line 132, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/rest_api/scripts/daily_analysis_report.py", line 105, in main
    table_summary = pcharts.analytics_table_chart(past_days_metrics, report_params, table_title)
  File "/home/ubuntu/rest_api/scripts/plotly_charts/charts.py", line 82, in analytics_table_chart
    py.image.save_as(table, filename=file_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 787, in save_as
    img = cls.get(figure_or_data, format, width, height, scale)
  File "/home/ubuntu/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 710, in get
    raise exceptions.PlotlyError(return_data['error'])
KeyError: 'error'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I can't find solution and reason behind this behaviour, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to get the `return_data` from `plotly/plotly.py` when running with jenkins. It seems that return_data doesnt contains the key `error`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, But plotly.py is library file, We can't change it. Any other reason or solution.

Comment: copy a plotly to your source code folder and try to make your script use that one.Then you can do whatever you want with the plotly.